# How to set Request Body parameter in rest api

Tags: java, request, response, jbpm, httpconnection

I have api using curl

`curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/containerid/tasks/210/expiration" -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{ \"java.util.Date\" : 1540025263987}"`

Now I want to call this api using java code :

I am using `javax.ws.rs.PUT` class for api calling and `HttpConnection` class.

I have set the requestMethod(POST) and request property.
This is url i am using :
`http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/"+containerId+"/tasks/"+taskId+"/expiration`

```java
url = new URL( http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/"+containerId+"/tasks/"+taskId+"/expiration);
conn.setRequestMethod(PUT);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

I want to pass this parameter to api but not sure which method to use ?

```json
{java.util.Date:1534343434"};
```

This parameter is passed in body.

Can anyone suggest how do I pass this parameter in java rest api ??

Comment: *"not sure which method to use"* --- `conn.getOutputStream()`

Comment: It works. Thank you